# Keyup event in the textbox is showing some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, datatables

I have one datatable which has six columns and last column hastextboxes. The textbox of number type which is as below:

```
<input type="number" name="payment-textbox" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" class="payment" placeholder="--" value=""/>
```

Now I need to apply 3 validations on that on keyup event:

1. It can take maximum value of 99999.99.
2. It should not allow user to enter more than 2 digits after decimal.
3. If user enter a value which is less than value of its fifth column respective value, an alert statement must be shown.

So I put below jQuery code. First two validations are working perfectly fine without any delay. But third validation is showing delay.

```
$('input.payment').on("change paste keyup", function(event) {
     var max = parseFloat($(this).attr('max'));
     var num = parseFloat($(this).val());

   //First Validation
    if ( num >= max) {
         $(this).val("99999.99");
    }  

   //Third Validation
    var totalAmount = $(this).closest('tr').find(".total-due-class").html();
    if($(this).val() < totalAmount)
    {
        alert("Error");
    }

 //Restrict user to enter only two digits after decimal point
     var number = ($(this).val().split('.'));
    if (number[1] && number[1].length > 2){
         var amount = parseFloat($(this).val());
          $(this).val( amount.toFixed(2));
    }
 });
```

Comment: It wouldn't be related to any "delay," but note that `html` and `val` both return **strings**, so `if ($(this).val() < totalAmunt)` will be doing a *string comparison* (in which, for instance, "10" is less than "2").

Comment: Separately: Look into the `input` event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please elaborate more. I couldn't understand.

Comment: On what? Comparing strings when you probably were supposed to be comparing numbers?